# Converting prefix to infix

Tags: evaluation, syntax, core-language

Is there a way in Mathematica to convert prefix to infix notation (where precedence order is preserved)?

For example, how would I convert `S[a, S[b, c]]` to `a ~ S ~ (b ~ S ~ c)`?

I checked the cookbook and also on line for "prefix to infix transformation". but did not find this topic.

Comment: I noted that Infix[S[Infix[S[a, b]], c]]  produces (a ~ S ~ b) ~ S ~ c   So it's a matter of nesting the Infix operation in this way. Not sure how to achieve it in Mathematica.

Comment: Perhaps via MapAll? But then only applied to non atomic (non leaf) parts?

Comment: MapAll[Infix, S[a, S[b, c]]] gives Infix[a] ~ S ~ (Infix[b] ~ S ~ Infix[c]) so my remaining question is how to not apply Infix to a, b and c.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
With[{S = Infix[S[##]] &}, S[a, S[b, c]] ]
```

> a ~S~ (b ~S~ c)

Also

```
S[a, S[b, c]] /. S -> (Infix[S[##]] &)
```

> a ~S~ (b ~S~ c)

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful. I will go with the second option.

Comment: Slightly neater is `S -> Infix @* S`.

Comment: @CarlWoll, yes!! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You could just give `S` a format:

```
MakeBoxes[S[a_, b_], StandardForm] ^:= MakeBoxes[Infix[S[a, b]], StandardForm]
```

Then:

```
S[a, S[b, c]]
```

> a ~S~ (b ~S~ c)

Comment: Thanks much appreciated.